# pixiedust installation issue with undefined modules

Tags: installation, anaconda, jupyter, pixiedust

Tried installing pixiedust for debugging functionality in Jupyter. Using standard conda environment , python 3.5 and following https://ibm-watson-data-lab.github.io/pixiedust/install.html
Up to "pip install pixiedust", everything is fine, but
"jupyter pixiedust install" reveals several modules which are not installed..  I suspect this may be wrong, and that they should have been installed by the pixiedust? After adding 5-6 modules (conda / pip)  I gave up.. What is wrong? Having a good debugger would be nice for jupyter.

Comment: Please include the actual error messages you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here. I use python 3 and ubuntu, but when I type 'pip install pixiedust', it was installing in python 2 (ubuntu's default).

What worked for me:

pip3 install pixiedust

pip3 install pixiedust_node

With that I can use the %%pixie_debugger in my cells and it works just fine.